# What mechanism causes failure in a BJT when collector current is exceeded?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Does exceeding the rated collector current of a [BJT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor) cause the device to fail because it suddenly heats up very fast? Or is there some other reason?

If the reason is heat, I'm wondering if I can exceed that current by immersing the device in a bath of liquid N2. If some other reason, are there any other tricks I might use to exceed that current?

Comment: Yes, heat is the big killer, softening or melting the wirebonds or the device itself. Yes, cooling often gives more headroom - key question being can you _keep_ it cool.

Comment: Why did someone close the question? Asking about the physical mechanism that causes some other phenomenon is certainly a physics question, not an engineering one. Can you please re-open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transistors of all types commonly fail when the junction temperature is high enough to enable *electromigration*, in which the diffused structures that form the junctions are ruined by thermally-activated diffusion which is biased by the presence of electric fields. A commom rule-of-thumb is that the transistor must not be operated at a temperature roughly equal to that which was present when the junction structure was originally created.

Comment: Interesting! So as long as junction temperature << junction creation temperature is the device safe?

Comment: That is what is usually assumed when setting limits on Tmax for a semiconductor. note that for very short, high power bursts, there's no time for the heat in the junction to get out through the lead frame and so the junction will pop even though the temperature on the outside of the transistor case may be below the Tmax. finally, note that the resistance of a junction goes down as the temperature goes up which means that once the device starts to heat up, it will try to draw more current and get hotter still- which is called *thermal runaway*.